# Invoking brill tagger through C#

Tags: c#, tagging

We want to use brill tagger such that on a button click, it will tag the Input.txt into output.txt. So we have created a new visual studio project and put a button. On button click event we wrote the following code.  There are no errors and we can see the command prompt getting invoked. But the output file is not getting created. The code is as follows. could you pls guide us??

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     ProcessStartInfo brillStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Users\toshal\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\brill tagger\bin\brill.exe");
        brillStartInfo.Arguments = "/C brill.exe LEXICON.BROWN Input.txt BIGRAMS LEXICALRULEFILE.BROWN CONTEXTUALRULEFILE.BROWN > output.txt";

        brillStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        brillStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        brillStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        brillStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

        Process brill = new Process();
        brill.StartInfo = brillStartInfo;
        brill.Start();
        string output = brill.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        brill.WaitForExit();

    }
```

Comment: @ Toshal Mokadam, first try to accept some previous answers before asking a question.

Comment: Do you mean creating output from the cmd command or the C# redirection code? If the latter, you aren't doing anything with your `output` string.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the file is created, just not in the directory you expect. Reason is, you launch cmd which default WorkingDirectory is `C:\Windows\system32`, just put the full path for the output file and should work or set the `process.WorkingDirectory` property.

Moreover, you want to redirect the output of your program to the C# app, you should not redirect it in your command line.

Either you redirect your output to a file with `> "outputpath"` or either you redirect output to you C# app then remove `>output`, both cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

They way your code is written, I think it should look like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ProcessStartInfo brillStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd");
    brillStartInfo.Arguments = "/C brill.exe LEXICON.BROWN Input.txt BIGRAMS LEXICALRULEFILE.BROWN CONTEXTUALRULEFILE.BROWN > output.txt";
    brillStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\toshal\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\brill tagger\bin\";

    brillStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    brillStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

    Process brill = new Process();
    brill.StartInfo = brillStartInfo;
    brill.Start();
    brill.WaitForExit();
}
```

Important change: The executable to execute is `cmd` and you need to set the working directory to the directory of brill.exe to be able to use it in the arguments without specifying the path.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the program is redirected into the file `output.txt`. If you let the program to generate output to the console, then `string output = brill.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` will return the result of tagging. Otherwise you have to open and read the file explicitly.